# How to install and run shadow-cljs in an existing project folder while on macOS?

Tags: npm, clojurescript, macos-monterey, shadow-cljs, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I am trying to install [shadow-cljs](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs.git) in a MacOS Monterey 12.5. I am new to the Apple ecosystem, to npm, and Clojure/ClojureScript stack. This a new world for me.

This is the project folder, as you can see there is already a `package.json` file:

```bash
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air balance % ls -l1
LICENSE
README.md
config
dev.cljs.edn
docs
externs
firebase-deploy.my-instance-specific-variables.TEMPLATE.edn
firestore.rules.json
makefile
package-lock.json
package.json
project.clj
public
semantic
semantic.json
shadow-cljs.edn
src
tools
```

This is the content of the `package.json` file:

```js
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air balance % cat package.json 
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "description": "xxxx",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "email": "xxxxxxx"
  },
  "license": "unlicensed",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "shadow-cljs watch app;",
    "release": "shadow-cljs release app;",
    "server": "shadow-cljs server;",
    "clean": "rm -rf target; rm -rf public/js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app": "^0.4.22",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.11.8",
    "@firebase/database": "^0.4.12",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^1.6.4",
    "@firebase/logger": "^0.1.28",
    "@firebase/webchannel-wrapper": "^0.2.29",
    "@js-joda/core": "3.2.0",
    "@js-joda/locale_en-us": "3.1.1",
    "@js-joda/timezone": "2.2.0",
    "@sheet/core": "^1.20191114.1",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "firebase": "5.7.3",
    "highlight.js": "^9.16.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-flip-move": "^3.0.4",
    "react-highlight.js": "^1.0.7",
    "reactstrap": "^8.6.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.4.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.5",
    "smartystreets-javascript-sdk": "^1.9.2",
    "stripe": "^8.158.0",
    "tslib": "1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "shadow-cljs": "2.15.3"
  }
}
```

The [manual indicates](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_installation):

> If you have a package.json already and just want to add shadow-cljs
> run NPM
>
> $ npm install --save-dev shadow-cljs

Hence, I did:

```js
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air balance % npm install --save-dev shadow-cljs
```

Which retrieved the following error:

```js
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @js-joda/timezone@2.2.0
npm ERR! Found: @js-joda/core@3.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@js-joda/core
npm ERR!   peer @js-joda/core@">=1.11.0" from @js-joda/locale_en-us@3.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@js-joda/locale_en-us
npm ERR!     @js-joda/locale_en-us@"3.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   @js-joda/core@"3.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @js-joda/core@"^1.11.0" from @js-joda/timezone@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@js-joda/timezone
npm ERR!   peer @js-joda/timezone@"^2.2.0" from @js-joda/locale_en-us@3.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@js-joda/locale_en-us
npm ERR!     @js-joda/locale_en-us@"3.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   @js-joda/timezone@"2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @js-joda/core@1.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@js-joda/core
npm ERR!   peer @js-joda/core@"^1.11.0" from @js-joda/timezone@2.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@js-joda/timezone
npm ERR!     peer @js-joda/timezone@"^2.2.0" from @js-joda/locale_en-us@3.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@js-joda/locale_en-us
npm ERR!       @js-joda/locale_en-us@"3.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     @js-joda/timezone@"2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/pedro/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pedro/.npm/_logs/2022-08-01T14_36_59_868Z-debug-0.log
```

After reading other questions on Stack Overflow around *upstream dependency conflict*, I tried **without success** the following:

```bash
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air balance % npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save-dev shadow-cljs
```

Which returned a **different** error message on `querystring` legacy:

```js
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air balance % npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save-dev shadow-cljs

npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/pedro/projects/balance/node_modules/semantic-ui
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/install-64525ec5.sh
npm ERR! fs.js:47
npm ERR! } = primordials;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
npm ERR!     at fs.js:47:5
npm ERR!     at req_ (/Users/pedro/projects/balance/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.req [as require] (/Users/pedro/projects/balance/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pedro/projects/balance/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Node.js v18.7.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pedro/.npm/_logs/2022-08-01T14_45_00_773Z-debug-0.log
```

I also tried another suggestion:

```bash
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air balance % npm list --depth=3
```

Which retrieved:

```js
tallyfor-balance@0.3.0 /Users/pedro/projects/balance
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @firebase/app@^0.4.22
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @firebase/auth@^0.11.8
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @firebase/database@^0.4.12
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @firebase/firestore@^1.6.4
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @firebase/logger@^0.1.28
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@^0.2.29
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @js-joda/core@3.2.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @js-joda/locale_en-us@3.1.1
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @js-joda/timezone@2.2.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY @sheet/core@^1.20191114.1
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY create-react-class@^15.6.3
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY firebase@5.7.3
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY highlight.js@^9.16.2
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY process@^0.11.10
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY react-dom@^16.11.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY react-flip-move@^3.0.4
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY react-highlight.js@^1.0.7
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY react@^16.11.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY reactstrap@^8.6.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY semantic-ui-react@^0.82.5
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY semantic-ui@^2.4.2
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY shadow-cljs@2.15.3
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY smartystreets-javascript-sdk@^1.9.2
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY stripe@^8.158.0
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY tslib@1.10.0

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: @firebase/app@^0.4.22, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @firebase/auth@^0.11.8, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @firebase/database@^0.4.12, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @firebase/firestore@^1.6.4, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @firebase/logger@^0.1.28, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@^0.2.29, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @js-joda/core@3.2.0, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @js-joda/locale_en-us@3.1.1, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @js-joda/timezone@2.2.0, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: @sheet/core@^1.20191114.1, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: create-react-class@^15.6.3, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: firebase@5.7.3, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: highlight.js@^9.16.2, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: process@^0.11.10, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: react-dom@^16.11.0, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: react-flip-move@^3.0.4, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: react-highlight.js@^1.0.7, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: react@^16.11.0, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: reactstrap@^8.6.0, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: semantic-ui-react@^0.82.5, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: semantic-ui@^2.4.2, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: shadow-cljs@2.15.3, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: smartystreets-javascript-sdk@^1.9.2, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: stripe@^8.158.0, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: tslib@1.10.0, required by tallyfor-balance@0.3.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pedro/.npm/_logs/2022-08-01T14_44_49_026Z-debug-0.log
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air balance % npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save-dev shadow-cljs
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/pedro/projects/balance/node_modules/semantic-ui
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/install-64525ec5.sh
npm ERR! fs.js:47
npm ERR! } = primordials;
npm ERR!     ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
npm ERR!     at fs.js:47:5
npm ERR!     at req_ (/Users/pedro/projects/balance/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
npm ERR!     at Object.req [as require] (/Users/pedro/projects/balance/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pedro/projects/balance/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Node.js v18.7.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pedro/.npm/_logs/2022-08-01T14_45_00_773Z-debug-0.log
```

Using the global flag also did not solve:

```bash
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air balance % npm install -g npm                                   


changed 14 packages, and audited 202 packages in 1s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

I am unsure about what else to try.

Any suggestion? Did I miss something?

Observation.: I am able to successfully run the [quick start example](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs#quick-start) on GitHub README of `shadow-cljs` repo.

```
Last login: Mon Aug 1 16:40:55 on ttys000
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air ~ % cd projects 
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air projects % cd acme-app 
pedro@Pedros-MacBook-Air acme-app % npx shadow-cljs node-repl
shadow-cljs - config: /Users/pedro/projects/acme-app/shadow-cljs.edn
shadow-cljs - server version: 2.19.8 running at http://localhost:9630
shadow-cljs - nREPL server started on port 50748
cljs.user=> shadow-cljs - #4 ready!
(+ 99 1)
100
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an existing project like this you just run `npm install`, without any additional arguments, to install all the dependencies listed in `package.json`. `npm ci` also works, which is sort for clean-install, if you have an existing `package-lock.json` it'll ensure to install the exact versions that were previously used.

However, your project seems to be a bit dated which means that the `npm` version you use may be newer than the one used at the time the project was created. This is why you may need to run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` instead.

When you do `npm install shadow-cljs` (or any other variant you tried) it'll tell `npm` to only install `shadow-cljs` and ignore the rest, which explains all the unmet dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. There were a lot of problems with the project. The documentation was not clear on things like: which java version to run, which version of node, which commit id to checkout on a dependency, on what branch... So, full dependency hell. I thought the problem was my use of npm commands or my use of shadow-cljs, but it was not the case.

Comment: As a general rule Java and Node should use the latest LTS releases, there has been close to no breakage in these for a long time. `npm` packages themselves however are a different story, they constantly break. This is what the `package-lock.json` is for, if the project had one. If kept in version control it at least ensures you get the exact same versions every time. If not actually in version control you are out of luck and truly in dependency hell.